# Is there value in asking a question that there already is an answer to?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for the answer to a question and I couldn't find anything. So my own question, was ready to post it, then paused to look at the "Similar questions". After scrolling for quite a bit, I discovered one that seemed to be the same question I had.

I think the reason I so far before finding it is because the title of the question didn't have any keywords I would think to search.

Therefore, am I benefiting the community by intentionally asking the same question so search engines can find it better?

Alternatively, should I edit the title when this occurs? It seems like that may not be as good, because others may think of the keywords I never would've thought of.